# Wireless dropping every 10 min on dell xps 7590 after upgrade to 20.04. requires stopping wifi and restarting it repeatedly. Worked fine in 19.10

Tags: networking, wireless, dell, 20.04, xps

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list

```
3b:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [1a56:1654]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
3c:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTS525A PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:525a] (rev 01)
```

...

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of these terminal commands: `dmesg | grep iwl` and also: `nmcli device wifi list` Please remove the BSSID (MAC address) numbers like this: xx:xx:xx. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Look at the logs with `sudo journalctl -b 0 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager`

Comment: [888790.091181] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[888790.259466] iwlwifi 0000:3b:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring

Comment: nmcli device wifi list
IN-USE  BSSID              SSID            MODE    CHAN  RATE        SIGNAL  BARS  SECURITY         
 6435E0          Infra   11    130 Mbit/s  87      ▂▄▆█  WPA1 WPA2        
 6435E0_5G       Infra   149   270 Mbit/s  72      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2        
 6435E0          Infra   11    195 Mbit/s  64      ▂▄▆_  WPA1 WPA2

Comment: Don't know how to attach the large NetworkManager output here.

Comment: <pre>un 20 22:23:19 daniel-xps-7590 NetworkManager[1038]: <font color="#D7D75F"><b>&lt;warn&gt;  [1592706199.5721] sup-iface[0x55761ccd0120,wlp59s0]: connection disconnected (reason -3)</b></font>
Jun 20 22:23:19 daniel-xps-7590 NetworkManager[1038]: &lt;info&gt;  [1592706199.5722] device (wlp59s0): supplicant interface state: completed -&gt; disconnected

Answer (score 0):

First, check the settings in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, if your router is capable of N speeds, you may have better connectivity with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz, although it is likely to affect N speeds. I recommend a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. Also, be certain the router is not set to use N speeds only; auto B, G and N is preferred. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/crda
```

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

If these changes do not help, please try:

```
sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi
sudo modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y
```

If it helps, make it permanent:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi disable_11ax=Y"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```